# Oracle: Show special text if field is null

Tags: oracle, select, null

I would like to write a select where I show the value of the field as normal except when the field is null. If it is null I'd like to show a special text, for example "Field is null". How would I best do this?

```
// Oracle newbie
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like to use function `COALESCE` for this purpose. It returns the first non-null value from given arguments (so you can test more than one field at a time).

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 'Special text') FROM DUAL
```

So this would also work:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
   First_Nullable_Field, 
   Second_Nullable_Field, 
   Third_Nullable_Field, 
   'All fields are NULL'
) FROM YourTable
```

Comment: +1 because `COALESCE()` works for mysql and other SQL Servers as well, not just ORACLE.

Answer (score 4):

Just insert the NVL PL/SQL function into your query

SELECT NVL(SOMENULLABLEFIELD,'Field Is Null') SOMENULLABLEFIELD
FROM MYTABLE;

More detail here : http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php

Comment: That should be single quotes not double quotes for the string literal

Answer (score 3):

You could also use DECODE:

```
select value, decode(value, NULL, 'SPECIAL', value) from 
  (select NULL value from dual
   union all
   select 2 value from dual
  )
```

Comment: Well, if we're going to suggest unnecessarily wordy solutions to a simple problem... how about `CASE WHEN mycolumn IS NULL THEN 'It''s NULL, baby' ELSE mycolumn END`

Comment: Point taken - NVL / COALESCE is indeed much cleaner and shorter than DECODE.

Comment: +1, even though it's not the most elegant solution to the question, it helped me out when I need to show one text for null and a different text for not null.